# Dropdown list which depends on active/inactive status of a neighboring cell (Excel 2010)

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, dropdownlist

I'm using Excel 2010

I have a spreadsheet to track my time charging.  I have all of the charge numbers in Table1 and I use a drop-down list in another sheet to select the charge code to use for each period of time worked.

I'd like to have an column to designate each code as active/inactive to use for filtering in Table1.  My problem is that all the codes show up in the drop down, so it's become a long list.  Is there a way to create a drop down list which only displays "active" charge codes?

Answer (score 0):

To keep things organised, make sure the column that has your codes is named "code"

- add table column "active" to mark activity (use `TRUE` for active codes)
- add table column "selected codes" with formula `=IF([@active],[@code],"")` This column only displays the active codes, but still on the original row.

Now at this point you could be done by referring to this column for your drop down list, and sorting the table on the active column once you have set which codes are active. If you want to automatically get the sorted list continue.

- add table column "active code ID" and put this formula in: `=IF([@[selected codes]]="","",COUNT($C$2:[@[selected codes]]))` $C$2 should be replaced with an absolute reference to what is the top row in your "selected codes" column. This gives a unique number to all selected codes.
- add table column "filtered codes" and in the top cell put the formula: `=IFNA(INDEX([code],MATCH(ROW(A1),[active code ID],0)),"")` This will find the code for ID 1 in the first row, 2 in the second etc...

Now if you really want to get fancy and have your drop-down list automatically expand when you add a new entry do the following:

- create a named range called "list_codes" and put `=Table1[filtered codes]` in the "refers to:" box
- When creating your drop down menu with data validation put `=list_codes` as source.

You should now have an dropdown list that automatically updates and sorts itself when you update the activity column, and updates when you expand the table.